# High speed usb webcam

Tags: cameras

I am looking for a high speed usb webcam.

The plan is to rotate the camera at about 20-30 revolutions per second, the problem is this requires me to have a framerate of about 120fps (depending on the lense...) and secondary the exposure time needs to be really short for the image not to be blurred (and still have a decent quality).

At the moment i am using a 120fps USB-Webcam by ELP but the results are not satisfiying (the image is used by a computer-vision algorithm which needs a more or less sharp image).

Is there any camera available which can achieve the desired results (and is quite small and lightweight). Money is not our primary concern.

Answer (score 1):

[image: With a 1.4 gigapixel-per-second throughput, you can capture stunning high-speed video at up to 1280x1024 resolution. Frame rate ranges from 1,057fps at full resolution, up to 21,500fps at minimum resolution.​ but the price is bit absurd.]

[image: These are the frame rates]

With a 1.4 gigapixel-per-second throughput, you can capture stunning high-speed video at up to 1280x1024 resolution. Frame rate ranges from 1,057fps at full resolution, up to 21,500fps at minimum resolution.​ but the price is bit absurd.
I guess this will do.

Answer (score 0):

I would contact the professional computer vision folks, such as Cognex, and maybe National Instruments.  Your camera requirements are quite challenging for off-the-shelf USB cameras which are not designed to support high-speed automation.